Maven Multi-module project: module project not "seeing" metamodels from sibling
I have a multi-module project with two siblings.
Project A has metamodel definiton as below in pom.xml
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0-jdk8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <processors>
                                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Project B has project ! as dependency in it's pom.xml, as below:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Project B is A's sibling and, it needs to access/read A's metamodel classes but, it seems B project cannot "see" A's metamodel in maven compile
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/parent-project/project-b/src/main/java/com/acme/SomeClassUsingMetamodel.java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class MetamodelClass_
location: package com.acme.project-b.model.someentity
Am I missing some configuration?

Project B's pom file would need to have a dependency on project A.

Project B already has project A as dependecy...
In Intellij there's no compiling  error...only via maven I receive compiling error...any idea of what I'm missing?

Possibly IntelliJ is set up with project A on the classpath which doesn't mean anything when doing a maven build.  What is the pom.xml of project B?  Is there an <dependency>... defined in project B for project A?

yes, project B has a  for project A in "provided" scope.

Seems like provided should work for compilation, but perhaps it's related to some transitive dependency.  Try compile scope?

yes...compile scope returns same error

Please post all pom.xml files in full.
